# Is there a general-purpose printf-ish routine defined in any C standard

Tags: c, printf, c99

In many C libraries, there is a printf-style routine which is something like the following:

```
int __vgprintf(void *info, (void)(*print_function(void*, char)), const char *format, va_list params);
```

which will format the supplied string and call print_function with the passed-in info value and each character in sequence.  A function like fprintf will pass __vgprintf the passed-in file parameter and a pointer to a function which will cast its void* to a FILE* and output the passed-in character to that file.  A function like snprintf will create a struct holding a char* and length, and pass the address of that struct to a function which will output each character in sequence, space permitting.

Is there any standard for such a function, which could be used if e.g. one wanted a function to output an arbitrary format to a TCP port?  A common approach is to allocate a buffer one hopes is big enough, use snprintf to put the data there, and then output the data from the buffer.  It would seem cleaner, though, if there were a standard way to to specify that the print formatter should call a user-supplied routine with each character.

Comment: Just out of interest, can you give an example of such a library?  I've never seen that before, and it does sound like it could be useful.

Comment: I've never seen it before either, and passing a `char` at a time looks extremely inefficient. Also using `char` as a function argument type is usually not advisable. `int` would be a lot more appropriate, but `char *` and `size_t` would make more sense.

Comment: @R: Passing a char at a time isn't wonderfully efficient, but when efficiency is required one isn't apt to use printf anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any standard for such a function, which could be used if e.g. one wanted a function to output an arbitrary format to a TCP port?

You can wrap a file descriptor or a socket into `FILE*` using [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fdopen.html) and pass it into `fprintf()`. However, this does not work with non-blocking sockets.

Formatting in a buffer first gives you much greater flexibility and the ability to use it with non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Formatting into a buffer is nice, but won't work for things like `printf("%.2000000000d", 0);` Admittedly this is an extreme example, but the huge advantage in general of using functions that write to a `FILE` directly rather than first constructing the whole string is that you never have to worry about allocation and failure cases.

Comment: @R..: presumably then the workaround in the absence of a `__vgprintf`-like function is to pass a pipe into `fprintf`, and use `fork` or threads to keep it from blocking. Sounds like effort, but fortunately only needed to allow for extremes, since for sane cases there's always the return value from C99 snprintf.

Comment: @Steve: `pipe` size is too limited on Linux. A regular file on `tmpfs` (in-memory) filesystem can be more flexible. On Linux there are also POSIX functions [`open_memstream()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) and [`fmemopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html)

Comment: @Maxim: I think R..'s point is that *memory* is too limited. In his extreme example you need 2GB, which some systems can manage and others cannot, but all systems "should" be able to write 2GB of data to a socket given sufficient time. You might get more out of an in-memory filesystem just because it doesn't necessarily need contiguous address space, but those others are no better than `snprintf` in this respect.

Comment: @Steve: the limits of built-in types are well known, one needs only a known fixed maximum amount of memory to print an integer or a real number at its full precision. Originally the OP was talking about formatting into TCP sockets, now it is `"%.2000000000d"`... Anyway, I would agree if there was a version of `sprintf()` accepting a pair of C++ iterators that would be awesome, this way one could format into ring buffers without copying...

Comment: @Maxim: In C++, the natural way to achieve the functionality would be to have ??printf accept a method pointer; since a method pointer would essentially be a combination of some type of pointer, and a pointer to a function whose first argument is of that type, the most idiomatic approach in C would be to pass a void* and a function pointer.

Comment: @supercat: true, but is it going to be a call through the pointer for each character? If not, then there is going to be some buffering and copying involved, i.e. not zero-copy.

Answer (score 2):

`open_memstream` is standard in POSIX, and *might* be standardized as part of the C language in the upcoming C1x standard. However this does not offer you an arbitrary callback; it requires that the whole output fit into memory, so it's really not any better than using `snprintf` (possibly wrapped by a function that automatically allocates a buffer).

On POSIX systems, one solution is to make a pipe to a new thread, and then use `dprintf` (or `fdopen` and `fprintf`) to write to it. The thread will receive the input on the other end of the pipe and can process it however it likes. Of course this is mildly slow (at least a couple syscalls every time output is flushed, and possibly a context switch if you have too few cores available) but it does what you want. The same approach will work on any system with pipes, threads, and the equivalent of `fdopen` or `dprintf`, so you should be able to make it work on Windows too if needed.

Another approach is to use `tmpfile`, `fprintf`, and `fread` (all standard C). A good implementation of `tmpfile` could even create a virtual file in memory, and postpone any actual file creation until `fileno` is called or the "file" size exceeds a certain limit.

**Edit:** Upon rereading the question, it seems OP just needs to use `fprintf` with sockets. In that case, `fdopen`/`fprintf` or `dprintf` accomplishes the task directly.

Comment: The TCP output was just one example of something output could be sent to.  Other things I've used are graphical output, etc.

Comment: Nice wrap up. Still kind of misses the point: for blocking file descriptors and sockets C standard `fdopen()` is enough. For non-blocking file descriptors one has to format into a buffer first anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Nonstandard, but take a look at `fopencookie` on Linux and `funopen` on BSD.  It might be possible to have wrap them in a standard API from your application, since they're very similar.  I believe that Cygwin and Mac OS X support at least one of the two as well.

Both functions allow you to create a `FILE *` with function pointers for reading, writing, seeking, and closing the stream.  Once created, you can `fprintf` into the stream.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt there is such a standard function, but you can of course create your own implementation to try and mimic it. Sorry.

Comment: Hmm.  Implementing a `printf`-like function by hand is not a trivial task!

Comment: And there is no need to reimplement that, you can always pass your own `FILE*` or format into memory.